# How to return outer function if any of the inner functions returns

Tags: python, python-3.x

See the following example:

```
def a(test):
    if test > 1:
        raise Exception("error in 'a'")
    print("nothing happened")

def b(test):
    if test > 1:
        raise Exception("error in 'b'")
    print("nothing happened")

def c(test):
    if test > 1:
        raise Exception("error in 'c'")
    print("nothing happened")

def all():
    try:
        a(1)
    except Exception:
        print("finished due to error")
        return False
    try:
        b(2)
    except Exception:
        print("finished due to error")
        return False
    try:
        c(1)
    except Exception:
        print("finished due to error")
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    all()
```

Output for this is:

```
nothing happened
finished due to error
```

So what I want to achieve is for `all()` to finish, returning False, when any of the inner function fails.

Is there any way to write the `all()` function like this, modifying the inner functions from the inside, so that they communicate the "return False" to the outer function?

```
def all():
    a(1)
    b(2)
    c(1)
```

(Current output of this would be):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matiaseiletz/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/aaa.py", line 24, in <module>
    all()
  File "/Users/matiaseiletz/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/aaa.py", line 18, in all
    b(2)
  File "/Users/matiaseiletz/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/aaa.py", line 8, in b
    raise Exception("error in 'b'")
Exception: error in 'b'
nothing happened
```

And the objective is to have an output like the first one, but without all the `try - except` logic around every function.

Thank you very much

Comment: FYI there's already a built-in function named `all()`, you should use a different name for your function.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a single `try/except` around the whole function body.

```
def my_all():
    try:
        a(1)
        b(2)
        c(1)
    except Exception:
        print("finished due to error")
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite this:

```
    try:
        a(1)
    except Exception:
        print("finished due to error")
        return False
    try:
        b(2)
    except Exception:
        print("finished due to error")
        return False
    try:
        c(1)
    except Exception:
        print("finished due to error")
        return False
```

as simply:

```
    try:
        a(1)
        b(2)
        c(1)
        return True  # assuming you want to do this on a success?
    except Exception:
        print("finished due to error")
        return False
```

This is a big part of the point of `try/except` blocks -- the `try` block continues as long as there isn't an exception, and the first exception raised immediately breaks execution and goes to the matching `except` (if any).  There's no need to wrap each line in its own `try` unless you want to handle the exception for each line differently.

Writing it as a reusable function, you might do something like:

```
def try_all(*funcs_and_args) -> bool:
    try:
        for func, *args in funcs_and_args:
            func(*args)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print("finished due to error:", e)
        return False

try_all((a, 1), (b, 2), (c, 1))
```

which produces the output:

```
nothing happened
finished due to error: error in 'b'
```

Your `except` could also print things like `func.__name__` and `args` if that information would be useful for debugging.